# STM32F103xx Option bytes getting corrupted?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I am using STM32F103c6 cortex-m3. I am using 100 micro controllers in various boards.
In some around 10 micro controllers, I have seen a issue of option bytes getting corrupted.
Even though I am writing 0xA5 to RDP to remove read protection while flashing, sometimes it makes memory read protected and few times it work properly.
The remaining 90 MCUs works fine!
Even the WRP also gets corrupted in those 10 MCUs.
No where I am making Read protected in code, only write protection ! (Write protection is also removed at flashing by setting 0xA5 on RDP)
Could it be because of power fluctuation? As we are doing few auto power interrupt tests!!
What could be issue?
I flashed the MCU multiple time which are misbehaving without running the code( just flashing with RDP 0xA5, sometimes it flashes, sometimes it gets read protected and doesnot Flash)!!

Did the MCUs gone bad??

Comment: What are you using to flash them?

Comment: Green hills probe using SWD. I also tried st-link (SWD).